# what is the equivalent of ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING in Spark?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to use, rowsBetween(-1, 0) on a column, but it seems not working. but when i use lag it is working fine.

My question is both `lag` and `rowsBetween(-1,0)` is same or not?

**Update:**
The reason i was using rowsBetween is i'm trying to convert `Teradata [ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING]`

Is `lag` equivalent to `ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING`?

**Sample code:**

```
df.show()
w = Window.partitionBy(df['ResId']).orderBy(df['vrsn_strt_dts']).rowsBetween(-1, 0)
lagWin = Window.partitionBy(df['ResId']).orderBy(df['vrsn_strt_dts'])
df.withColumn("vrsn_end_dts", max(df['vrsn_strt_dts']).over(w)).show()
df.withColumn("vrsn_end_dts", lag(df['vrsn_strt_dts']).over(lagWin)).show()
```

**output:**

```
+--------+-------------------+---------+------------+-------+----------+
|   ResId|      vrsn_strt_dts|instnc_nm|ship_strm_nb|vyge_id|onhand_cnt|
+--------+-------------------+---------+------------+-------+----------+
|27608171|2018-07-17 04:00:00| Standard|         11B|   1000|        10|
|27608174|2018-08-17 04:00:00| Standard|         11C|   2000|        20|
|27608173|2018-09-17 04:00:00| Standard|         11D|   3000|        30|
|27608171|2018-09-17 04:00:00| Standard|         11B|   1000|        40|
|27608174|2018-09-17 04:00:00| Standard|         11D|   5000|        50|
|27608171|2018-09-18 04:00:00| Standard|         11B|   1000|        10|
|27608171|2018-09-19 04:00:00| Standard|         11B|   1000|        10|
+--------+-------------------+---------+------------+-------+----------+
```

**with Rowsbetween output**

```
+--------+-------------------+---------+------------+-------+----------+-------------------+
|   ResId|      vrsn_strt_dts|instnc_nm|ship_strm_nb|vyge_id|onhand_cnt|       vrsn_end_dts|
+--------+-------------------+---------+------------+-------+----------+-------------------+
|27608171|2018-07-17 04:00:00| Standard|         11B|   1000|        10|2018-07-17 04:00:00|
|27608171|2018-09-17 04:00:00| Standard|         11B|   1000|        40|2018-09-17 04:00:00|
|27608171|2018-09-18 04:00:00| Standard|         11B|   1000|        10|2018-09-18 04:00:00|
|27608171|2018-09-19 04:00:00| Standard|         11B|   1000|        10|2018-09-19 04:00:00|
|27608174|2018-08-17 04:00:00| Standard|         11C|   2000|        20|2018-08-17 04:00:00|
|27608174|2018-09-17 04:00:00| Standard|         11D|   5000|        50|2018-09-17 04:00:00|
|27608173|2018-09-17 04:00:00| Standard|         11D|   3000|        30|2018-09-17 04:00:00|
+--------+-------------------+---------+------------+-------+----------+-------------------+
```

**with lag output**

```
+--------+-------------------+---------+------------+-------+----------+-------------------+
|   ResId|      vrsn_strt_dts|instnc_nm|ship_strm_nb|vyge_id|onhand_cnt|       vrsn_end_dts|
+--------+-------------------+---------+------------+-------+----------+-------------------+
|27608171|2018-07-17 04:00:00| Standard|         11B|   1000|        10|               null|
|27608171|2018-09-17 04:00:00| Standard|         11B|   1000|        40|2018-07-17 04:00:00|
|27608171|2018-09-18 04:00:00| Standard|         11B|   1000|        10|2018-09-17 04:00:00|
|27608171|2018-09-19 04:00:00| Standard|         11B|   1000|        10|2018-09-18 04:00:00|
|27608174|2018-08-17 04:00:00| Standard|         11C|   2000|        20|               null|
|27608174|2018-09-17 04:00:00| Standard|         11D|   5000|        50|2018-08-17 04:00:00|
|27608173|2018-09-17 04:00:00| Standard|         11D|   3000|        30|               null|
```

Comment: If I understand it correctly you need to use `min` function instead of `max`.

Comment: @VolodymyrGlushak: i need to use max only, but my question is both lag and rowsBetween(-1,0) is same right? it should return same output right?

Comment: No! `lag` gives you just a value from previous record. `max` of two dates: previous record and current gives you latest date.

Comment: Your test already show that they are not the same. What is the actual question here?

Comment: @Shaido: changed the question, please check now

Comment: So what output do you want? You want to get the same output as `lag` while using rowsBetween(-1,0)? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, the same output as lag but using rowsBetween? is it possible?